# QPlainTextEdit checking some condition

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create my own very simple editor of .txt files. As in real editors, I want that if you change the file and don't save it yet, the name of file will start with '*' (for example, *some_text_file.txt).

I think that fot this I should check QPlainTextEdit after the file was downloaded to editor and after the user pushed button 'save'. But I don't know how to check QPlainTextEdit without user control, but after some changes. Or maybe there is another way to do it. So, how to do it?

Comment: With "name of file" do you mean the window title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `textChanged` signal from the `QPlainTextEdit`. It indicates when the input text has changed. See:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#textChanged

Roughly, you would do the following:

- load the file
- display the filename without asterisk
- connect the `textChanged` signal into a slot (function) that will add asterisk to the filename
- when the Save button is pressed, remove the asterisk

If you're a Qt beginner, you might want to read about the Qt signal and slot mechanism:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Note that `textChanged` is fired *whenever* the text is changed, and it doesn't consider the modified state of the document, which might be important for undo/redo operations: typing a character and deleting it is *not* the same as typing a character and triggering the `undo()` command.